# Обработать запрос и вернуть переменную

Tags: python, django

Только начинаю разбираться в python и django.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обработать GET - запрос и вернуть переменную в классе DetalViews?
Сейчас делаю так:

```
class QuestDetalViews(DetailView):
model = Quest
template_name = 'qst/quest_detail.html'
    def get(self, request, slug, **args):
        if 'answer' in request.GET and request.GET['answer']:
            answer = request.GET['answer']
        return super(QuestDetalViews, self).get(answer, request, slug, **args)
```

Но на страницу не возвращается answer.
Подскажите, что тут не так?

Comment: Разобрался, сделал через get_context_data:

Comment: было бы неплохо ответить на собственный вопрос, возможно кому-то пригодится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cделал так:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuestDetalViews, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        answer = self.request.GET.get('answer')
        context['answer'] = answer.lower().lstrip().rstrip()
        return context
```